# gitlab not executing git command from git

Tags: git, bash, gitlab-omnibus, gitlab-8

I have successfully installed GitLab Community Edition 8.15.2 (omnibus) on my local ubuntu server 16.04 with apache2 (2.4), i can access it in browser and can perform all tasks. But when i try to execute task (like pushing project for first time or cloning project) using git bash or git gui, it does not perform the task e.g.

```
git clone http://192.168.179.128/pherry/Pilzon.git
```

it gave following output

```
Cloning into 'Pilzon'...
fatal: unable to access 'http://192.168.179.128/pherry/Pilzon.git/': The requested URL returned error: 500
```

So i looked into production.log file when i executed the following line

```
git clone http://192.168.179.128/pherry/Pilzon.git
```

and this was the log

```
Started GET "/pherry/Pilzon.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack" for 192.168.179.1 at 2017-01-09 20:00:17 -0800
Processing by Projects::GitHttpController#info_refs as */*
  Parameters: {"service"=>"git-upload-pack", "namespace_id"=>"pherry", "project_id"=>"Pilzon.git"}
Filter chain halted as :authenticate_user rendered or redirected
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 41ms (Views: 0.3ms | ActiveRecord: 5.2ms)
Started GET "/" for 192.168.179.1 at 2017-01-09 20:00:19 -0800
Started GET "/" for 192.168.179.1 at 2017-01-09 20:00:19 -0800
Processing by RootController#index as HTML
Processing by RootController#index as HTML
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 44ms (ActiveRecord: 19.3ms)
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 28ms (ActiveRecord: 4.3ms)
```

then it asked for password and when i provided it and this was the log

```
Started GET "/pherry/Pilzon.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack" for 192.168.179.1 at 2017-01-09 20:01:52 -0800
Processing by Projects::GitHttpController#info_refs as */*
  Parameters: {"service"=>"git-upload-pack", "namespace_id"=>"pherry", "project_id"=>"Pilzon.git"}
Filter chain halted as :authenticate_user rendered or redirected
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 32ms (Views: 0.6ms | ActiveRecord: 3.5ms)
Started GET "/pherry/Pilzon.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack" for 192.168.179.1 at 2017-01-09 20:01:52 -0800
Processing by Projects::GitHttpController#info_refs as */*
  Parameters: {"service"=>"git-upload-pack", "namespace_id"=>"pherry", "project_id"=>"Pilzon.git"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 149ms (ActiveRecord: 5.6ms)

JWT::DecodeError (Nil JSON web token):
  lib/gitlab/workhorse.rb:137:in `decode_jwt'
  lib/gitlab/workhorse.rb:133:in `verify_api_request!'
  app/controllers/concerns/workhorse_request.rb:11:in `verify_workhorse_api!'
  lib/gitlab/middleware/multipart.rb:93:in `call'
  lib/gitlab/request_profiler/middleware.rb:15:in `call'
  lib/gitlab/middleware/go.rb:16:in `call'
```

i have been searching for solution for a day and have not found it yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a similar issue with [22532](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/22532), alluding to a `gitlab-workhorse` mismatch version after an upgrade..

[Issue 23133](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/23133) also mention the `JWT::DecodeError (Nil JSON web token)` error message and points to [`gitlab-recipes` issue 57](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-recipes/issues/57), with the possible fix:

> Short answer, need to change `/etc/init.d/gitlab` so `gitlab-workhorse` listens on a TCP port rather than using unix sockets, then set up an Apache rewrite to that port.

(see more [at this comment](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/2669#note_2179396))

Comment: changed line gitlab_workhorse['listen_addr'] = "/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-workhorse/socket"  to  gitlab_workhorse['listen_addr'] = "localhost:8282", in /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb, rest was already setup after installation, every thing working now. Thanks @VonC